# python setup.py can't find package in company pypi

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I'm trying to get `python setup.py install` and its brethren (*not* requirements.txt) to find a package in a local company pypi repository run from artifactory.

I've read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#examples and I *think* what I need is a URL based lookup as described there. (I played a bit with `dependency_links` before figuring out that it seems that has been removed in favor of the PEP-508 approach.)

I can get to my package in a browser at

```
http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my_package/
```

and if I use

```
pip install --index https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/ my_package
```

(or if I set `index-url` in ~/.pip/pip.conf) it installs successfully.

But I can't figure out a working syntax in the `install_requires` list for `setup.py`.

I *think* it should be something like

```
my_package@https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/
my_package@https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my_package
my_package@https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple/my_package/some-wheel-or-something.n.m.o
```

Help?